# Simple Adsearch for emails

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get a list of emails from an ADGroup. The problem is there are members in the group that have no emails and I want the variable to show the ADuser instead of the email if the field is empty.

current code is this

```
$emails = get-adgroupmember gg-sccm-admins  | get-aduser -Properties emailaddress | select emailaddress
$emails+= get-adgroupmember gg-sccm-site_admins  | get-aduser -Properties emailaddress | select emailaddress
Write-Output $emails
```

My idea was to use an IF and if the email field is empty write username in the variable but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could use below:

```
$emails = get-adgroupmember gg-sccm-admins  | Get-ADUser -Properties emailaddress | select @{N="EmailAddress";E={if($_.emailaddress){$_.emailaddress}else{$_.samaccountname}}}
$emails+= get-adgroupmember gg-sccm-site_admins  | Get-ADUser -Properties emailaddress | select @{N="EmailAddress";E={if($_.emailaddress){$_.emailaddress}else{$_.samaccountname}}}
Write-Output $emails
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do both?

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Emails = @()
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Names = @()

[array]$GroupMembers = Get-ADGroupMember "gg-sccm-admins" | Get-ADUser -Properties emailaddress,DisplayName | Select EmailAddress, DisplayName
    Foreach($user in $GroupMembers){
$null = $Emails.Add($User.EmailAddress)
$null = $Names.Add($User.DisplayName)
    }

For($i=0;$i -lt $Names.count;$i++){
    [pscustomobject]@{
        "User Names" = $Names[$i]
        "Emails" = $Emails[$i]
                    }
            }
```

Also, instead of using a fixed array, I changed it to an ArrayList. Should make the process faster as it doesn't have to recreate each array each time with a new item.